# CircleCI 2.0 delete merged Git branch

Tags: git, github, circleci

I was wondering if there is an option to delete a branch after a merge build is finished in Circle CI. From what I saw, we only have available a CIRCLE_BRANCH env variable, which provides the name of the branch being built, but I am interested in the branch being merged, so that I can trigger a branch delete from inside the the config.yml file.

Comment: Can you show us the command(s) you are using to do the Git merge? The Git repo will almost certainly contain enough information to do a subsequent remote branch delete. It may be worth showing how you differentiate between an ordinary branch build and a merge build (I am guessing you don't always want to merge).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to a solution with this:

```
MESSAGE="$(git show -s --format=%s $1 | grep 'Merge pull request')"
 if [ -z "${MESSAGE}" ]; then
    echo 'Not a merge commit message'
   exit 1
fi
BRANCH="$(git show -s --format=%s $1 | grep -oE '[^ ]+$')"
# extract actual branch name that gets deleted
BRANCH="$(echo $BRANCH | sed -e 's/PaymentFusion\///g')"
# command used to remote delete branch that was merged
git push origin --delete $BRANCH
```